# In eclipse (sapui5 application ) Deploying in hana cloud portal

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

Part1
From eclipse When I deploy it(Sapui5 application) I see the application deployed in hana cloud portal

I see  application in java applications--Categery

My doubt is why it is not deployed in HTML5 applications category?
What is the difference in between this both?

Part2

Can I now use the odata servise from the HCP account(I registed  the system in hcp account) to ecclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTML5 section used mostly for client-side applications developed in WEB IDE. You created a SAPUI5 application which has, I assume, both client and server sides. This type of projects go to Java applications section.
2. Refer to [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d12024e38385472a89c1ad204e1edb48.html)  example of using Northwind OData service.